# Python code to draw a path on a map with arrows using lat/long data

Tags: python, python-3.x, maps

Along with time and heading, I also have the latitude & longitude data. From the data, I want to draw a path with arrows that indicate the path a vehicle took.

I can create a path, but I am not able to make arrows on the path, in order to specify the path and the direction, it took.

I want to create a plot that looks like the image below.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Can you give us an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using matplotlib, you could use `quiver`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# Arrow locations
lon = [1,1,2,2]
lat = [1,2,2,1]
# Arrow directions
x_dir = [1,0,-1,0]
y_dir = [0,-1,0,1]
# add to plot using quiver
ax.quiver(lon,lat,x_dir,y_dir,angles='xy', scale_units='xy')
plt.show()
```

I cannot be more precise with info you provided, but above logic could be used.